# RESTful/JAX-RS with Swift?

Tags: java, rest, stream, swift

I have built an Android application, which exchanges data with a server. For this purpose, there is a RESTful web service running on the server, written in Java with JAX-RS. The tricky thing is: I do exchange the data between application and server via Streams (Object- or FileOutputStream for example).

Now I want to build the same application for iOS, using Swift. Is there a way that I can read those Streams with Swift? And it is of course not only the reading of the Stream. As I do send Java Object, for example a String, can I receive this Object in Swift? I think it is not possible and I have to get rid of all that Streaming stuff and use Media.Types. But maybe I do have a chance to leave it like that?

Any ideas?

Comment: GREAT! Go downvote but provide no answer. This is ridiculous...

Comment: I compensated that and suggest the same for you in similar situations as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating yourself a lot. The two apps should never have anything to do with each other. No matter what ecosystem they're running on (whether iOS, Android, Windows, etc) they shouldn't have to be aware of each other at all.

The same applies to the service. It shouldn't be concerned about which client is being consumed by. It should only care about receiving a "client-agnostic" request and serve the response. Now, the service would be SOAP/XML, plain json text, whatever. It's the client's responsibility to produce the correct request and understand the response from the server.

So, to answer your question...

> Is there a way that I can read those Streams with Swift? And it is of course not only the reading of the Stream. As I do send Java Object, for example a String, can I receive this Object in Swift?

No, you're iOS app shouldn't have to deal with java code, it should only need to make the correct request to the server and understand the response...i.e. by making a service request using a `NSURLConnection` and parsing the response

So, just focus on making the service endpoint(s) platform-agnostic so that any client can consume it

Comment: Ok, well I was already expecting this kind of answer. My problem is: I have not written the server, only the application. I know how I can change it though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ZerO seriously, I don't see any other answer to your question. Now, I'd recommend you design the service first before you even write a single line of code to consume the service, this way you can easily plan ahead and avoid the overload of re-designing your solution